# Get toDataURL from canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image-uploading

I'm uploading a photo via `AngularJs` I'm trying to retrieve the DataURL from the canvas that I create the image too, however it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

When I upload one photo which is of type `jpg` it works and I get the dataUrl, however when I upload another photo again which is of type `jpg` it's intermittent and doesn't alert the dataUrl

This is my currently html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="scopeExample">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
  <img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{data.UserPhoto}}" id="photo-id"/>
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)" id="photo-upload"/>
{{greeting}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my angular controller with the uploadFile function:

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.uploadFile = function (input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {

        alert("inside");

            //Sets the Old Image to new New Image
            $('#photo-id').attr('src', e.target.result);

            //Create a canvas and draw image on Client Side to get the byte[] equivalent
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var imageElement = document.createElement("img");

            imageElement.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);

            canvas.width = imageElement.width;
            canvas.height = imageElement.height;
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0);

            var b = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            alert(b); // sometimes alerts value, sometimes doesn't.

           // var imageinBase64=base64Image.replace(/data:image\/jpg;base64,/g, '');
        }

        //Renders Image on Page
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with the code or maybe explain why it sometimes alerts the dataUrl and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Any error in console ? Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Hey, I've tried to get this into jsFiddle unfortunately I've not worked with it before and I kept getting console errors regarding AngularJS etc

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/hv8nygpd/

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks for adding it to JsFiddle, now the issue is the second alert it doesn't pass me back the dataUrl i.e alert(b)

Comment: It does....Have tested it...

Comment: @RayonDabre all I get in the alert is `data:,` I would expect the base64 string or am I missing something?

Comment: Check with the different files..It is working fine at my end..